# Binding Frame.BackgroundProperty with ImageBrush in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to set background of `rootFrame` by binding and I have some problems with it.

I have this code but it doesn't work...

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
myBinding.Source = DataModel.Settings;
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedBackgroundIndex");
myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
myBinding.Converter = new BgIndexToBgConverter();
rootFrame.SetBinding(Frame.BackgroundProperty, myBinding);
```

I think I'm doing it wrong and I should first create `ImageBrush` then bind Source of it.
This code works but how to implement it with binding?

```
rootFrame.Background = new ImageBrush
{
     Stretch = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Stretch.UniformToFill,
     ImageSource = new BitmapImage { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Backgrounds/" +  
     DataModel.Settings.SelectedBackgroundIndex.ToString() + ".png") }
};
```

I tried to create `new ImageBrush()` with `BitmapImage` and bind source of Uri to it but I had a lot of messy code that didn't work anyway so I won't copy it here.

**EDIT:**
Converter gives back the path to corresponding background image.

```
int index = (int)value;
string path = "ms-appx:///Assets/Backgrounds/" + index.ToString() + ".png";
return path;
```

and `SelectedBackgroundIndex` is integer property with notification

```
private int selectedBackgroundIndex;
public int SelectedBackgroundIndex
{
     get
     {
          return selectedBackgroundIndex;
     }
     set
     {
          selectedBackgroundIndex = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedBackgroundIndex");
     }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are binding to an Index, so there has to be something interesting going on with the converter. Post the converter code and all relevant parts of `DataModel.Settings`. Otherwise I can't really tell whats going wrong. And what does "doesn't work" constitute? No brush, not switching or what?

Comment: I updated question. Doesn't work means that there is no background at all (it's black).

Comment: There is your error the background needs a brush not a path I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you converter return a brush instead of a path:

```
int index = (int)value;
ImageBrush retValue = new ImageBrush
{
    Stretch = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Stretch.UniformToFill,
    ImageSource = new BitmapImage { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Backgrounds/" + index.ToString() + ".png") }
};
return retValue;
```

Of course make that nicer and do error checking and so on, but this gets the idea across.

Additionally I would not make this a two way binding. There is not really a way to translate a brush back into an index.

Comment: It did the job but it looks like it can't be bound like this because background doesn't change when I change the value of SelectedBackgroundIndex (rootFrame isn't notified?). I'll try to figure this out somehow. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Set a breakpoint into your converter, if it doesn't get hit after you set the index you  don't receive the notification, and go from there (inspect the output window to look for errors and so on). I it does get hit then there is an error in the converter and debug that.